# Highlight.js custom language definition

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I'm trying to create language definition for **highlight.js**.
But it doesn't work. I've got an example.

In this example i'm trying to create custom *"aaa"* language, which is the same as JSON. `registerLanguage` function receives same function as a default JSON highlight function (from highlight.js sources).

`hljs.listLanguages()` shows, that language is registered.

After, i'm calling `hljs.highlightBlock(block)`.

`<code class="aaa">` forces to use custom "aaa" language, and in this case `hljs.highlightBlock(block)` doesn't changes  content.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // registering aaa language (JSON alias)
  // code from https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/master/src/languages/json.js
  hljs.registerLanguage("aaa", function(hljs) {
    var LITERALS = {
      literal: 'true false null'
    };
    var TYPES = [
      hljs.QUOTE_STRING_MODE,
      hljs.C_NUMBER_MODE
    ];
    var VALUE_CONTAINER = {
      className: 'value',
      end: ',',
      endsWithParent: true,
      excludeEnd: true,
      contains: TYPES,
      keywords: LITERALS
    };
    var OBJECT = {
      begin: '{',
      end: '}',
      contains: [{
        className: 'attribute',
        begin: '\\s*"',
        end: '"\\s*:\\s*',
        excludeBegin: true,
        excludeEnd: true,
        contains: [hljs.BACKSLASH_ESCAPE],
        illegal: '\\n',
        starts: VALUE_CONTAINER
      }],
      illegal: '\\S'
    };
    var ARRAY = {
      begin: '\\[',
      end: '\\]',
      contains: [hljs.inherit(VALUE_CONTAINER, {
        className: null
      })], // inherit is also a workaround for a bug that makes shared modes with endsWithParent compile only the ending of one of the parents
      illegal: '\\S'
    };
    TYPES.splice(TYPES.length, 0, OBJECT, ARRAY);
    return {
      contains: TYPES,
      keywords: LITERALS,
      illegal: '\\S'
    };
  });
  console.log(hljs.listLanguages()); // aaa in the list
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/tomorrow.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/highlight.min.js"></script>
<pre><code class="aaa"> 
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

Highlight.js have a minification/packing process during build that renames the fields of the language definition objects. This means that the objects they describe in http://highlightjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/language-guide.html won't work with the distributed library. Only languages defined before build time will work this way.

You could look in the minified highlightjs file for usages of registerLanguage to try and reverse engineer the names of fields.

Comment: This file contains all replaced names: https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/905119aad47d4bb3d4fbaa14df7598034dccb6a3/tools/utility.js